# Django - getting POST to return a dictionary where the values are lists

Tags: python, django, post

been stuck on this one for a while:

We've got a view that has a number of dishes on it, like this:

```
spaghetti
tacos
burger
```

we want to have the user be able to enter two pieces of information related to each dish, a grade and a comment. for example

```
spaghetti: 20, "tasty"
tacos: 10, "nasty"
```

however, we can't seem to find a way to give the input boxes for the grade and the comment the same name so we'd get back a POST dictionary where the values are lists themselves:

```
spaghetti: [20,"tasty"]
tacos:  [10, "nasty"]
```

if we name the input box and the comment box both "spaghetti" in the html form, then POST only tracks the second thing which is the comment, and the grade is completely lost, so all we get back is:

```
spaghetti: "tasty"
tacos: "nasty"
```

let us know what we're doing wrong!!

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're just going to have to use a different id for each grade and comment, then do some server side parsing to format your data nicely.  Either that or you can do client side parsing and use a $.post to send JSON data to the server.  I'd lean towards the second option, honestly, although you'll still have to do some server side validation/data sanitization.

If you go for the second option, you could do something like this:

```
<div id='spaghetti'>
  <input field-type='grade' />
  <input field-type='comment' />
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=submit]').click(function() {
      var data = {}
      var grade = $('#spaghetti').children('input[field-type=grade]').first().val();
      var comment = $('#spaghetti').children('input[field-type=comment]').first().val();
      data['spaghetti'] = [grade, comment];
      $.post('url', data);
    }
  }
```

Comment: thank you for this suggestion and the example code! going to play with it today.

Answer (score 0):

In the form, name one spaghetti_grade and another spaghetti_taste. Then you can access them using:

`request.POST.get('spaghetti_grade','')` and `request.POST.get('spaghetti_taste','')`

that will allow you to get both without the need for a list. You can then do the same for the other foods.